# How do you clear the beginning rendered animations for a series in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts

Some clarification first. **There are several kinds of animations in high charts.** I am only interested in the **beginning animation** that draws a line graph when **adding a series**.

That being said, it appears that if a series is in the middle of its beginning animation and is removed, the animation will finish drawing and stay permanently on the chart. A new series that is added will not redraw.

Is there a way to remove that specific series' beginning animation, or redraw the chart in order to refresh it? I assume recreating the entire chart can accomplish this but it will not serve my purposes. I need the first series to remain drawn without triggering the beginning animation for the first, but the second has to have a beginning animation so that it can animate over top of the first.

Here's an example of the issue for reproduction

```js
$(function () {
 var data1 = [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104];

 //var animatedData = { color: '#FF00FF', data: data1 };
 var animatedData = { data: data1 };
 var data = [{name: "USA", data: data1}, animatedData];
 
 function reanimateChart() {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
  chart.series[1].remove();
  chart.addSeries(animatedData);
  chart.redraw();
 }
 
 $('#btn1').click(function () {
  reanimateChart();
    });
 
 $('#btn2').click(function () {
  reanimateChart();
  setTimeout(reanimateChart, 100);
 });
    
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: 1940,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: data
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <div><button id="btn1">reanimate</button></div>
    <div><button id="btn2">break animation</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check this example http://jsfiddle.net/j86jkfvj/67/ which allows to pause/stop/run again the animation.

Comment: I've had to step back from this functionality due to some urgent projects, but so far the example works great. Thanks for the input.